# Azure service bus and strongly typed messages. Is it ok to share code between microservices?

Tags: azure, architecture, microservices, azureservicebus

I am developing a number of microservices. They will communicate through azure service bus. I would like the messages to be sent and received as strongly typed objects.

Am I violating the microservice principles by creating a bunch of classes to represent the messages?

I would probably put these classes in a nuget package, that I use in each of the microservices. Any examples or best practice you can point me to on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call this 'violation' but rather a design choice. For example, when using wear abstraction such as NServiceBus or MassTransit, you're by design using [strongly typed messages](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/messages-events-commands#designing-messages). Those are contracts and are expected to be [shared](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/sharing-contracts) between services.